# Phone app freezes after using iPhone for a few hours

Tags: iphone, ios, phone.app

When the phone is switched on and I open the Phone app I can navigate to "Recents", "Contacts" and other tabs there. But after about few hours using the iPhone, when I press the Phone app, it goes to that, but I cannot navigate to any tab or do anything. Everything is frozen there.

If I double-press the home button and close the Phone app and reopen it, it is still not working and freezes. If I restart the phone, then it is working for the first few uses, and after a while it's the same. There are no errors in other apps, just in this, and this is a huge impact for me since I cannot even dial a number.

How can I fix this? I am on iOS 9.1 (the latest version at the time of writing) on iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: Do you by any chance have some weird issues in your address book?

Comment: @mccc I don't think so. Because even when it(the phone button) freezed I can access the contacts without any problem by going to contacts via spotlight search. My worry is I cannot access the number pad, where I need to make a call